# Squeaky hydo brakes

Tags: brakes

I have hydraulic brakes and I've recently had new pads as the old ones were no good. I ride to work everyday so I know I've bedded them in. I've gone to go out on it today and both brAkes are squeaking really bad. They seem to be sharp when off the bike but soon as any weight Is on the bike they squeak and hardly work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What brakes are they? Did you replace the pads with the same ones that you took off (meaning same brand)? Was is damp/wet outside?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the brake pads and/or discs could be contaminated. Even the oil from your fingers can be enough to create a squeak.

Some disc brake cleaner, such as that made by Muc-off might help. Perhaps a change of pads.

[Check out this article](http://www.bikeradar.com/au/gear/article/workshop-step-by-step-guide-to-quiet-disc-braking-22829/)